# chef, Could not find cookbook in your cookbook path

Tags: chef-infra

in my chef-repo I added a cookbook

`cookbooks/mycookbook`

when i do

```
$ knife cookbook upload mycookbook
```

I get

```
ERROR: Could not find cookbook php-1.3.1 in your cookbook path, skipping it
Uploaded 0 cookbooks.
```

What did I do wrong here

Answer (score 2):

A [`config.rb`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb.html) file is used to specify configuration details for knife, which is loaded every time the knife executable is run and is located by default at `~/.chef/config.rb` (and if i am not mistaken, you can also place it within the your chef repository directory at `.chef/config.rb`).

make sure that you set `cookbook_path` in `config.rb`

> `cookbook_path`
>
> The Chef Infra Client sub-directory for storing cookbooks. This value can be a string or an array of file system locations, processed in the specified order. The last cookbook is considered to override local modifications. For example:
>
> ```
> cookbook_path [
>   '/var/chef/cookbooks',
>   '/var/chef/site-cookbooks'
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To re-iterate on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782030/1184717), not only do you have to configure your cookbook location in your knife/config.rb file, you also have to make sure that your dependencies are present in the cookbooks folders.

For instance your error message is about a specific version of php. To make sure the php cookbook gets uploaded alongside your cookbook, you could run the following commands while inside your cookbook folder  :

```
berks install
berks upload
```

This will ensure that all dependent cookbooks are uploaded alongside your main one. See example here :

[image: Berks]

Comment: correct, if you are using a monolithic chef repository, then also make sure that each of your custom cookbooks has a [default `Berksfile`](https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html#quick-start). though you might only use `berks install` and leverage [`knife upload`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_upload.html)