# Unable to create a file inside a cookbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, cookbook

Am learning chef by self study,am unable create a file inside my chef cook book

Fallowing are my steps,which i've done in linux instance

1. Created a Directoy(using mkdir command) named it as cookbooks
2. went inside the directory (using cd cookbooks)
3. generated cookbook (using chef generate cookbookt test-cookbook) and move inside the cookbook(using cd test-cookbook)
4. created a recipe (chef generate recipe test-recipe) and came back in to my my directory i;e out of of test-cookbook(using cd ..)
5. created a file using `vi test-cookbook/recipes/test-recipe.rd`, which looks like: 
   file '/myfile' do
     content 'hello'
     action:create
   end
6. i gave this command `chef exec ruby -c test-cookbook/recipes/test-recipe.rb` & the result is "Sytax ok"
7. now i gave this command `chef-client -zr "recipe[test-cookbook::test-rescipe]`, which is throwing me error:

   ```sh
   Missing Cookbooks:
   ------------------
   No such cookbook: test-cookbook
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens since you did not configure chef-client correctly. you are missing the `client.rb` file and the settings `cookboook_path` within it.

refer [to this answer for full details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782030/1184717)